# How to fix 'Cannot resolve Symbol "Append"'

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android development. I have been following up an example from developer.android.com in creating my first app. But now I am stuck with this. I will appreciate any help.

```
package com.avelmx.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    }

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.append(message);

}
```

Comment: `TextView` does have `#append()` but you need to write code inside a code block . In this case inside `#onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do **`findViewById()`** and **`textView.append(message);`** inside `onCreate()` method

Just move your code inside `onCreate()` it will work

Try this

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.append(message);
 }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreate()` should look something like the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not in a scope of a function, move your code into a function, and it will compile.

Comment: Man this is frustrating. Face punch

Comment: Did it work? If so, it is appropriate to upvote/select the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

hi replace this code :

```
package com.avelmx.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

// Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.append(message);

}
}
```